# Evaluating a limit using an integral of $x^5$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

The following problem is from the book, Calculus and Analytical Geometer by Thomas and Finney. I am hoping that somebody could check my work.
Problem:
Evaluate
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 +  ... n^5}{n^6} $$
by showing that the limit is
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^5 \, dx $$
and evaluating the integral.
Answer:
\begin{align*}
a &= 0 \\
b &= 1 \\
\Delta x &= \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1}{n } \\
n \Delta x &= 1 \\
\text{Let }f(x) &= x^5 \\
\text{Let }x_i &= i \Delta x + a = i \Delta x = \frac{i}{n} \\
\int_{0}^{1} x^5 \, dx &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} f(x_i) \Delta x \\
\int_{0}^{1} x^5 \, dx &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} x_i^5 \Delta x
= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{x_i^5} {n} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{ {\frac{i}{n}}^5 } {n} =
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{i^5}{n^6} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 +  ... n^5}{n^6} \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to evaluate the integral.
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} x^5 \, dx &= \frac{x^6}{1} \Big|_0^1 = \frac{1^6}{6} \\
\int_{0}^{1} x^5 \, dx &= \frac{1}{6} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: I think you wrote $\dfrac{x^6}1$ but meant $\dfrac{x^6}6$

Comment: I think your work is totally right.